# HOWTO link_directory directive to link CSS AND SCSS files with Sprockets 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I'm working on a Ruby on Rails 7 project using Sprockets 4, and it has both `.scss` and `.css` files in `app/assets/stylesheets/.`

The [documentation](https://github.com/rails/sprockets?tab=readme-ov-file#link_directory) for the `link_directory` directive says this:

> link_directory can take an optional second argument with an extension or content-type, with the two arguments separated by a space:

And provides this example to be used in `manifest.js`:

```js
//= link_directory ../stylesheets text/css
//= link_directory ../more_stylesheets .css
```

How would I tell Sprockets to link both `scss` and `css` files with `link_directory` directive?